# In my php my admin, password change and marked AllowNoPassword in ubuntu12.04

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, ubuntu-12.04

In my php my admin(mysql) was a password,but I change it and marked AllowNoPassword in ubuntu12.04.

After then I am unable to enter my phpmyadin it shows "Login without a password is forbidden by configuration (see AllowNoPassword)".

Please help me how can i access my mysql data or change my password.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is solved. For this I have used a command, for you I mentioned it below:

```
Stop the MySQL Server.

sudo /etc/init.d/mysql stop

Start the mysqld configuration.

sudo mysqld --skip-grant-tables &

Login to MySQL as root.

mysql -u root mysql

Replace YOURNEWPASSWORD with your new password!

UPDATE user SET Password=PASSWORD('YOURNEWPASSWORD') WHERE User='root'; FLUSH PRIVILEGES; exit;
```

Answer (score 0):

you should have the following lines in your config

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPasswordRoot'] = true;
```

[link](http://docs.oseems.com/general/web/phpmyadmin/enable-login-without-password)

Stop the mysql demon process using this command :

```
 sudo /etc/init.d/mysql stop
```

Start the mysqld demon process using the --skip-grant-tables option with this command

```
sudo /usr/sbin/mysqld --skip-grant-tables --skip-networking &
```

**Because you are not checking user privs at this point, it's safest to disable networking. In Dapper, /usr/bin/mysqld... did not work. However, mysqld --skip-grant-tables did.**

start the mysql client process using this command

```
 mysql -u root
```

from the mysql prompt execute this command to be able to change any password

```
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Then reset/update your password

```
SET PASSWORD FOR root@'localhost' = PASSWORD('password');
```

If you have a mysql root account that can connect from everywhere, you should also do:

```
UPDATE mysql.user SET Password=PASSWORD('newpwd') WHERE User='root';
```

[link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MysqlPasswordReset)

Comment: Ok, How can i change my password now,

Comment: SET PASSWORD FOR root@localhost = PASSWORD('yourpassword');

Answer (score 0):

```
You can run following command from the terminal for changing the user password:-

mysqladmin -u root -p PASSWORD YOUR_NEW_PASSWORD 

Press Enter
It will ask for current password 
Give current password there
Done
```

Comment: TQ, Ok the problem is solved. 
For this I have used a command, for you I mentioned it to below:

Stop the MySQL Server.

sudo /etc/init.d/mysql stop


Start the mysqld configuration.

sudo mysqld --skip-grant-tables &


Login to MySQL as root.

mysql -u root mysql


Replace YOURNEWPASSWORD with your new password!

UPDATE user SET Password=PASSWORD('YOURNEWPASSWORD') WHERE User='root'; FLUSH PRIVILEGES; exit;

Answer (score 0):

TQ, Ok the problem is solved. 
For this I have used a command, for you I mentioned it to below:

**Stop the MySQL Server.

sudo /etc/init.d/mysql stop

Start the mysqld configuration.

sudo mysqld --skip-grant-tables &

Login to MySQL as root.

mysql -u root mysql

Replace YOURNEWPASSWORD with your new password!

UPDATE user SET Password=PASSWORD('YOURNEWPASSWORD') WHERE User='root'; FLUSH PRIVILEGES; exit;

**